# Spring setting @value from another variable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-annotations, spring-config

Is it possible to set `@Value` from another variable

For eg.

```
System properties : firstvariable=hello ,secondvariable=world

@Value(#{systemProperties['firstvariable'])
String var1;
```

Now I would like to have `var2` to be concatenated with `var1` and dependant on it , something like

```
    @Value( var1 + #{systemProperties['secondvariable']
    String var2;

public void message(){ System.out.printlng("Message : " + var2 );
```

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't do that or you will get `The value for annotation attribute Value.value must be a constant expression`.

However, you can achieve same thing with following

In your property file

```
firstvariable=hello
secondvariable=${firstvariable}world
```

and then read value as

```
@Value("${secondvariable}")
private String var2;
```

Output of `System.out.println("Message : " + var2 )` would be `Message : helloworld`.

Comment: I need syntax to concat inside @Value

Comment: If your end objective is to concatenate value of var1 and var2, why don't you simply introduce an instance method as follow


`String getVar2() {
    return var1 + var2;
}`

Answer (score 2):

As the question use the predefined systemProperties variable with EL expiration.
My guess is that the meaning was to use java system properties (e.g. -D options).

As @value accept el expressions you may use

```
@Value("#{systemProperties['firstvariable']}#systemProperties['secondvariable']}")
private String message;
```

You said

> Now I would like to have var2 to be concatenated with var1 and
>   dependent on it

Note that in this case changing var2 will not have effect on message as the
message is set when the bean is initialized

Answer (score 0):

In my case (using Kotlin and Springboot together), I have to escape "$" character as well. Otherwise Intellij IDEA gives compile time error:

**Implementation gives error:**

```
@Value("${SCRIPT_PATH}")
private val SCRIPT_PATH: String = ""
```

**Error:** An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant

**Solution:**

```
@Value("\${SCRIPT_PATH}")
private val SCRIPT_PATH: String = ""
```